# Can't get file size because it apparently doesn't exist

Tags: python, path, size

I'm creating a code to get the size of all files inside folders from a directory.

```
    import os

    rootdir = "Z:"

    # Identifying all files and sizes, and putting them inside lists
    files = []
    sizes = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
        for f in filenames:
            sizes.append(os.path.getsize(dirpath + "/" + f))
            files.append(dirpath + "/" + f)
```

There are thousands of files and the code works well on most of them. Although there are some files that I get the following error when I try to get its size:

```
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified
```

I already checked if the path really exists with `os.path.isdir(rootdir)` for Z and also for other folders that the error above occurs, but they all exist.

This error occurs with different types of files (xls, pdf, jpg, doc, etc). For example, in these 2 files below, my code works only at the first one ("Thumbs.db"):

```
.../Thumbs.db
.../CS-2014-00-02832-1.jpg
```

IMPORTANT: when I renamed this image file to "test.jpg", then my code manage to read it and got its size.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem so I can get the size of all files without throwing an error?

Comment: It looks like you are on Windows and I see `/` as seperator instead of `\\`. Can this be the problem?

Comment: I already tried replacing this separator with '\'. But I also get the same error. The weird thing is that I can "read" some files, but not all of them

Comment: Use only backslashes in path and when using the path in `getsize` prepend `\\?\ ` (escaped as `'\\\\?\\'`). There is a path length limitation to 260 characters which can be lifted this way. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

Comment: Wow, thanks @MichaelButscher! That was it... a problem because of the path length